# Pick from both sides?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, dynamic-programming

The problem statement is :
Given an integer array A of size N.

You can pick B elements from either left or right end of the array A to get maximum sum.
Find and return this maximum possible sum.

NOTE: Suppose B = 4 and array A contains 10 elements then:

You can pick first four elements or can pick last four elements or can pick 1 from front and 3 from back etc . you need to return the maximum possible sum of elements you can pick.

```
public class Solution {
ArrayList<Integer> c = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Integer> A= new ArrayList<>();
public int solve(ArrayList<Integer> A, int B) {
   
    if (B>A.size()){
        int sum=0;
        for(int i=0;i<A.size();i++)
         sum= sum+A.get(i);
        return sum;
    }

   int max_sum=0;
 for(int i=0;i<A.size();i++){
  if((max_sum<suffix(A.size()-(B-i))+prefix(i-1)) ){
       max_sum=suffix(A.size()-(B-i))+prefix(i-1);
     }
    }
    return max_sum;
}
    
    int prefix_sum=0;
  int prefix(int a)   {
      
       for(int p=0;p<a+1;p++){
           c=A;
            prefix_sum=prefix_sum + c.get(p);
            }
          return prefix_sum;
                     }

           int suffix_sum=0;
           int suffix(int b){
               c=A;
        for(int q=b;q<c.size();q++){
           suffix_sum=suffix_sum+c.get(q);
          }
            return suffix_sum;
         }
```

}

I am getting runtime error, I have tried to implement the suffix and prefix methods which return the sum from the index[ 0, i] and sum from [i, N-i] respectively, then in the solve function I am trying to find the sum of prefix [a-1] +suffix[N-(b-a)] and find out the maximum sum, the syntax is completely correct, there is something wrong with the logic I assume, please help me find the correct solution by correcting this code instead of providing an alternative method

Comment: please add  the runtime exception you are receiving to your question

Comment: What runtime error are you getting and what line triggers it? Please post the entire stack trace.

Answer (score 4):

```
    package com.array;

    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.List;

    public class PickFromBothSides {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Integer[] arr = { 5, -2, 3, 1, 2 };
            System.out.println(solve(Arrays.asList(arr), 3));

        }

        public static int solve(List<Integer> A, int B) {

            int n = A.size();

            int result = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < B; i++) {
                result += A.get(i);
            }

            int sum = result;

            for (int i = 0; i < B; i++) {
                sum -= A.get(B - 1 - i);
                sum += A.get(n - 1 - i);

                result = Math.max(result, sum);
            }

            return result;

        }
    }
```

Runtime O(n)
Space complexity O(1)

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring `int prefix_sum=0;` and `int suffix_sum=0;` as fields, not as local variables of the respective methods.

You are calling `suffix(A.size()-(B-i))` so with your example that is `10 - (4 -i)` which is `6 + i`. You iterate through `i` being in the range {0, ..., 10} so the value `6 + i` will be all the numbers 6 through 16. You cannot index in the array above 9, so you get an exception.

You need to change

```
for(int i=0;i<A.size();i++){
```

to

```
for(int i=0; i <= B; i++){
```

because you are trying to ask each iteration "how many numbers are taken from the beginning"? 0, 1, 2, 3 or 4 if B is 4

---

Other upgrades:

1. You are calling `suffix(A.size()-(B-i))+prefix(i-1))` twice in a row. Call it only once, store it in a variable and reuse.
2. You are calling `prefix(i-1)` but inside prefix() you are using the parameter `a` as `a + 1`. You don't need to subtract one and add one to the same thing

Answer (score 0):

PFB another approach to solve this problem(in Python3):

```
 def solve(A, B):
        left = [0]
        for i in range(B):
            left.append(left[-1]+A[i])
        right = [0]
        for i in range(B):
            right.append(right[-1]+A[len(A)-i-1])
        for i in range(B+1):
            left[i] += right[B-i]
        return max(left)
```

Here I created a cumulative sum (or prefix and suffix sum) of B number of elements from the left and right sides of array A, Then added the sum of the first element of the left with the last element of the right. Thus finally returned the max of them.